# interpreting backbone collection data that it received from an api controller

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I'm trying to use a simple collection and view to write out data from my backbone collection to my website. I just want to iterate over the collection and display properties like Id, Name, etc. in my template.

My collection gets its data from an api controller(a sample of the data is shown below).

My limited knowledge leads me to guess that the api controller is returning an object and not JSON.

So I'm guessing that is messing up my results. I've written out the collection to my Chrome console and attached a screenshot of what I see below.

So looking at the code below, is there a way that I can format the data returned from the api so that my collection can use it effectively?

Here is the code:

```
   var ResearchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       url: '/api/lab',

       getresearch: function() {
           this.fetch({
               url: this.url
           });
       }
   });

var researchCollection = new ResearchCollection();

return Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'labRender',
    template: _.template(tmpl, null, { variable: 'x' }),

 render: function () {
        researchCollection.getresearch();
        console.log('collection: ', researchCollection);
     }
```

Basically, I just want to iterate over my collection and display properties like Id, Name, etc. in my template.

Here is the raw data from the api controller that I am using to populate my collection:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://sol.edu/SOM/Api/v1/$metadata#ApiKeys","value":[
    {
      "odata.id":"http://sol.edu/SOM/Api/v1/ApiKeys('2f2627ed-3a97-43aa-ac77-92f227888835')","Id":"2f2627ed-3a97-43aa-ac77-92f227888835","Name":"VideoSearch","TimeoutInMinutes":20160,"IsDefault":false,"CreateAuthTicketsForResources":false,"ReportAuthFailureAsError":false,"ExcludePrivatePresentations":true,"Internal":true,"ViewOnlyAccessContext":true
    }
  ]
}
```

when piped to the browser's console(why is each character a separate attribute?):

[image]

Comment: It happens when to set string into collection. new Backbone.Collection("someString") returns exactly what's on your screenshot. 

Add method "parse" to collection and inspect it's args via debugger (it being called after fetch). Response probably will be string.

Comment: parse what though?  thanks

Comment: It will pass you response to "parse" method. http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse.

By default it's empty function (no-op). But once you define it in collection you can format your responce from the server before set into collection.

parse: function(response) {
    return response; // inspect your response to see if it's not string.
}

If it's string you can parse it JSON.parse(response) or change return format on server side.

Comment: @SciFiThief Ok, I added just a simple parse like.. parse: function(r) { return r};  but the data looks the same.

Comment: Try to console.log(r), it should be string. If yes modify you parse like this:

parse: function(r) {return JSON.parse(r) }

Comment: I added the parse method below the url line in the collection.  Will the parse method be called when I call researchCollection.getresearch(); in my render method?

Comment: It should, because getresearch calls fetch and fetch will call parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe this is because you mixed up collection and model. In Backbone, `Model` are fundamental unit, a `Model` can be used to render a template.However, `Collection` are ordered sets of 'Models'. So, if you just want to transform a data like you describe above, you may better select a `Model` instead of 'Collection'. Just try this:

```
var ResearchModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

       initialize: function(attributes) {
           this.url = 'api/lab'
       }
   });

// when you initialize a Model or collection, the first parameter is the attribute you want to initialize
var researchModel = new ResearchModel({});

return Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'labRender',
    template: _.template(tmpl, null, { variable: 'x' }),

 render: function () {
        researchModel.fetch();
        console.log('collection: ', researchModel);
     }
```

Otherwise, if you just want to use collection, you had better specify its `Model`.Backbone use JSON, so you can also specify the model with your key.

Comment: well the url, /api/lab, returns a whole collection,  not just one model

Comment: In this case, on the one hand, you can change your data returned from your server, make it fit the format of model and collection.On the other hand, you can use underscore.js to parse the collection in your code.Just see here and may help you:http://underscorejs.org/